# How can I create a static library that links against another library and can be used by a third program that links both the libraries?

Tags: gcc, linker, openssl, static-libraries, fips

Sorry for the confusing wording.

Basically I want to create a static library (`libone.a`) that needs to link another static library (`libtwo.a`). `libone.a` **and** `libtwo.a` are both linked in statically into another program (let's call it `program`) by doing the following:

```
$(CC) -o program something.o anotherthing.o -L/path/to/lib -lone -ltwo
```

Whenever `program` makes a call to a method in `libtwo.a` it should go to the `libtwo.a` that is loaded with `program`. But whenever `program` makes a call to a method in `libone.a` which calls a method in `libtwo.a`, it should call the `libtwo.a` that was embedded in when `libone.a` was created. Yes I understand that this will blow up the file size by loading two of the same libraries but I'm OK with that.

The reason why I'm attempting this is because the `program` I have is using OpenSSL (in this case `libcrypto.a`) and my static library is also using `libcrypto`. However I have a requirement in my library that OpenSSL be FIPS valid (i.e. `FIPS_mode_set(1)`) but doing that will break `program`. In short I want to libraries of OpenSSL used. The one called by `program` natively should use its own and the one called by my library should use the one that I linked and is FIPS valid.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

No, this simply can not be done with archive libraries (it *can* be done with shared libraries  but requires great care to avoid symbol collisions).